# Adding arrays to multi-dimensional array within loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to generate a multi-dimensional array with each sub array representing a row I want to insert into my DB. The reason for this is so I can use CodeIgniters batch_insert function to add each row to the DB.

I am attempting to create each sub array within a loop and insert it into a multidimensional array. Google suggested using array_merge, but after using 'print_r' on the multidimensional array with the code below, only the last sub-array is being displayed.

Here is my code:

```
$allplayerdata = array(); //M-D container array
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++)
{
    $playerdata = array(
                        'player_id' => $this->input->post('player' . $i),
                        'goals' => $this->input->post('playergoals' . $i),
                        'player_num' => $i,
                        'fixture_id' => $this->input->post('fixture_id')
                    );

    //Merge each player row into same array to allow for batch insert
    $allplayerdata = array_merge($allplayerdata, $playerdata);
}
print_r($allplayerdata);
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is because `array_merge` is not the right operation for this situation. Since all the `$playerdata` arrays have the same keys, the values are overridden.

---

You want to use `array_push` to append to an array. This way you will get an array of `$playerdata` arrays.

```
array_push($allplayerdata, $playerdata);
```

Which is equivalent to adding an element with the square bracket syntax

```
$allplayerdata[] = $playerdata;
```

---

- [`array_merge` - Merge one or more arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
- [`array_push` - Push one or more elements onto the end of array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
- [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Answer (score 9):

This will add the second array to the first array: A *merge* is something different.

```
$allplayerdata[] = $playerdata;
```

Comment: I think you should clarify that merge replaces the elements with the same index. It would be more helpful that way