# Update a CSV file with php

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, fopen

These are my databases:

database.csv:

```
barcode,      Name     , Qty ,Code
123456 ,Rothmans Blue  , 40  ,RB44
234567 ,Rothmans Red   , 40  ,RB30
345678 ,Rothmans Green , 40  ,RB20
456789 ,Rothmans Purple, 40  ,RB10
567890 ,Rothmans Orange, 40  ,RB55
```

stocktakemain.csv:

```
barcode,      Name     , Qty ,Code,ScQty
123456 ,Rothmans Blue  , 40  ,RB44,  1
234567 ,Rothmans Red   , 40  ,RB30,  1
```

Process:

1. The website has an input scan that is posted to "barcode".
2. It will check that the barcode exists within 'database.csv'
3. IF the barcode exists and is NOT within the 'stocktakemain.csv', it will add it to 'stocktakemain.csv' with a ScQty of 1. Please see Section 2 within code below.
4. **ELSE when an existing barcode within stocktakemain.csv is scanned, append 'stocktakemain.csv' with +1 (an addition of 1) to ScQty for that particular line.**

**Bolded above is not working**

Code:

```
function searchForBarcode($id, $array)
{
   foreach ($array as $key => $val)
   {
        if (in_array($id, $val))
        {
            return $key;
        }
   }
   return null;
}

$post = $_POST["barcode"];
$dbcsv = fopen('databases/database.csv', 'r');
$csvArray = array();
while(! feof($dbcsv))
  {
      $csvArray[]  = fgetcsv($dbcsv);
  }
fclose($dbcsv);
$searchf = searchForBarcode($post, $csvArray);
$result = $csvArray[$searchf];
$final = $result[+3];

if ($searchf !== NULL){
$stcsv = fopen('databases/stocktakemain.csv', 'r+');
$stArray = array();
while(! feof($stcsv))
  {
      $stArray[]  = fgetcsv($stcsv);
  }
fclose($stcsv);

$searchs = searchForBarcode($post, $stArray);

if ($searchs === NULL) {
    $filew = 'databases/stocktakemain.csv';
    $write = file_get_contents($filew);
    $write .= print_r(implode(",",$result), true).",1\n";
    file_put_contents($filew, $write);
}
else {
    $filew = 'databases/stocktakemain.csv';
    $resultexisting = $stArray[$searchs];
    print_r($resultexisting);
    echo "<br/>";
    $getfilecont = file_get_contents($filew);
    $getfilecont = trim($getfilecont);
    $existing = explode(",", $getfilecont);
    $existing[4] = trim($existing[4]);
    ++$existing[4];
    print_r($existing);
    echo "<br/>";
    $writeto = print_r(implode(",",$existing), true);
    print_r($writeto);
    file_put_contents($filew, $writeto);
}
}
```

Comment: When you run it currently, and scan something that already exists in stocktakemain.csv, does it increment any ScQty in stocktakemain.csv? Or do nothing? Or error-out?

Comment: yes it does, but if there is multiple values in there, it will not include them when it re-writes.

Comment: is it going inside the else part what is the value of $searchs @atomapps

Comment: HI @saurabhkamble , $searchs determines whether the barcode scanned exists within 'stocktakemain.csv'. If 'null' is returned, it will write a new line to 'stocktakmain.csv', otherwise, the ELSE statement is run. This is where the problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some conclusions I've made from reading your code:

- The else block is executed if an item is scanned that is already in the stocktakemain.csv file
- `$searchs` contains the index of the row of the item that was scanned
- `$stArray` contains a 2D array of the stocktakemain.csv contents - the first index is the line number, starting at 0, and the next index is the column number

Based on this, I think you need to rewrite your else block to be something like:

```
$scQtyColumn = 4;

// what is the current quantity? 
$scQty = intval($stArray[$searchs][$scQtyColumn]);

// update the quantity in the stocktakemain.csv contents array
$stArray[$searchs][$scQtyColumn] = $scQty + 1;

// write each line to file
$output = fopen('databases/stocktakemain.csv', 'w');
foreach($stArray, $line) {
  fputcsv($output, $line);
}
```

Could you try that out and see if it does the trick?

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your reply. $stArray is not 2D, please see updated question which includes full code :)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I believe that `$stArray[]  = fgetcsv($stcsv);` adds the return value of fgetcsv to a new element in the array $stArray. Since [fgetcsv returns an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), you are adding one array for each line in the CSV file. Then you can use `$stArray[$lineNumber][$columnNumber]`. See the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892148/adding-arrays-to-multi-dimensional-array-within-loop

Comment: Incredible... you are spot on. Thank you so much... So much simpler that I had expected...